# Manipulate API Response to display organized list

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, sorting, vuejs2

I'm making an API call for a list of properties that are unorganized from the API. The data from the API is stored in vuex looks like this:

```
posts:[
  {
   id: 1;
   title: "Place",
   acf: {
     address: {
       state: "Arkansas",
       country: "United States"
     },
   },
  },
  {
   id: 2;
   title: "Place 2",
   acf: {
     address: {
       state: "Arkansas",
       country: "United States"
     },
   },
  },
  {
   id: 3;
   title: "Place 3",
   acf: {
     address: {
       state: "Arkansas",
       country: "United States"
     },
   },
  },
  {
   id: 4;
   title: "Place 4",
   acf: {
     address: {
       state: "Missouri",
       country: "United States"
     },
   },
  },
  {
   id: 5;
   title: "Place 5",
   acf: {
     address: {
       state: "Johor",
       country: "Malaysia"
     },
   },
  },
]
```

I need to organize the data to display in a v-for loop in the following format (with the United States first, then alphabetical):

- United States

  - Arkansas

    - Place
    - Place 2
    - Place 3
  - Missouri

    - Place 4
- Malaysia

  - Johor

    - Place 5

It is my understanding I should be using a computed function for this, but cannot get the hierarchy of:

```
- Country
  - State 
    - Place
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a nested dictionary:

```js
computed: {
  dictionary() {
    const dictionary = {};
    this.$store.state.posts.forEach(post => {
      const c = post.acf.address.country;
      const s = post.acf.address.state;
      const t = post.title;
      dictionary[c] = dictionary[c] || {};
      dictionary[c][s] = dictionary[c][s] || [];
      dictionary[c][s].push(t);
    });
    return dictionary;
  }
}
```

The outer object has country names for keys.  Each country value is itself a similar object with state names as keys.  The state value is an array of places.

Comment: Oh you want this alphabetically sorted.  Does the data change at all while the app is running?

Comment: The data doesn't change while it's running.

Comment: A nested sort is non-trivial to do efficiently so I'll leave that alone